# undefined method `add_foreign_key'

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

i installed some project in my local with `git clone some_url`, and i did `bundle install` to install gems to my local.

and to migrate cloned database, i did `rake db:migrate`, then i got this message.

```
undefined method `add_foreign_key' for #<SomeMigrationFileName:0x0000000....> ...
```

how can i solve this error?

---

ps: is it MYSQL problem? `gem 'mysql2'` statement exists already in my `Gemfile`, but when i commanded `bundle install`, i got a install error message during installing MYSQL.

so i install mysql with, `brew install mysql`

Comment: Can you post that `migration file`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Foreign keys constraints are not something that rails supports out of the box (at least not until rails 4.2, which isn't out yet)

The easiest way is to use the [foreigner](https://rubygems.org/gems/foreigner) gem which adds support for this in migrations and in schema dumping.

Comment: I realized `add_foreign_key` didn't work for me because I was using `rails 4.1.8`.